# Views based on views based on etc

Tags: sql-server-2005, database-design

I have this script(dtsx file) on a sql 2005 server (made by some other technician), some stored procedures update tables with data from views. I can see that these views are based on other views, sometimes 4 to 5 layers thick before hitting the database tables. Would you recommend to improve this construction?

(when confronted with this script i found no documentation, so i don't know the motivation why this construction is used)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I would not recomend you change this, unless there is some logical, or business requirement that you change the structure.

Views on views is quite normal.

Have a read here

- [Using Views in Microsoft SQL Server](http://www.craigsmullins.com/cnr_0299b.htm)
- [SQL Server Views](http://odetocode.com/Articles/299.aspx)